# Calendar control in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add a calendar control with its associated buttons in asp.net with C#.

I have the code as below.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" CssClass="text-small" runat="server"
             BorderWidth="1px" ToolTip="Click to choose date"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblFromError" CssClass="Error" runat="server"
           Text="*" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblTo"  runat="server" Text="To" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtDateFrom_CalendarExtender" runat="server"
                      TargetControlID="txtDateFrom"
                      Format="yyyy-MM-dd" TodaysDateFormat="yyyy d, MMMM">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add an ImageButton and set the `CalendarExtender`'s `PopupButtonID` property to the ID of the ImageButton.

This is from the AjaxControlToolkit's sample web site:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" ID="ScriptManager1" />

<b>Calendar with an associated button:</b><br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Date5" />
<asp:ImageButton runat="Server" ID="Image1"
  ImageUrl="~/images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png"
  AlternateText="Click to show calendar" /><br />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calendarButtonExtender" runat="server"
  TargetControlID="Date5" PopupButtonID="Image1" />
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the JQuery plugin for Calendar. Check this [topic](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
 });
</script>

<div type="text" id="datepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this 
1. Add a ToolkitScriptManager
2. Add a TextBox Control
3. Add a CalendarExtender

Here is the complete code :

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">  
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>  

<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  

<asp:CalendarExtender   
    ID="CalendarExtender1"   
    TargetControlID="txtStartDate"   
    runat="server" />
```

Comment: I need to add image button for demonstrating calendar

Comment: @sanakkian - You want to add image button at the side of the textbox ? Then check out this link http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Comment: @sanakkian: You need to use the PopupButtonId and PopupButtonLocation properties - see the link Bibhu mentioned above.